# How to access module named lambda using amplify-swift sdk

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify, swift-package

I am developing a swift package with which I need to use aws lambda as well as cognito services. Inside the package when I include dependencies as

```
 dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios-spm",
                 from: "2.30.4"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift.git", from: "2.6.0"),
    ],
```

I am getting error of duplicate dependencies since the aws-sdk-swift inside the amplify sdk contains same modules as in AWS-mobile-sdk.

Amplify sdk is the recommended way for app development. My problem is I don't have a way to access both lambda and cognito services from amplify sdk alone. I am using AWS lambda to invoke a lambda function directly from the code.

How can we solve this by including the necessary components only?